# Breeze Metadata Api not getting called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

I looked at the network tab on Chrome and found that my breeze api for metadata is not getting called and thus all my methods of createEntity etc are failing.

```
      [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _context.Metadata();
    }
```

I have followed the todo example and have enabled CORS Support and just about everything, I can see the json metadata if i navigate to /api/breeze/metadata
I am using VS2012 Web Express and gotten all the packages thru nuget
dataservice.js

```
    app.dataservice = (function (breeze) {

    var serviceName = 'api/breeze'; // route to the same origin Web Api controller   

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

    return {
    createTodo: createTodo,
    saveChanges: saveChanges

    };

    function createTodo(initialValues) {
    return manager.createEntity('BreezeItem', initialValues);
    }

    function saveChanges() {
    return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(function () { alert('good') })
       .fail(function () { alert('bad') })
    }



})(breeze);

index.html
`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>

    <title>Breeze Todos with KO</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="applicationHost">
        <header>
        <h1>Breeze Todos</h1>
        <h2>with Knockout</h2>
        <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: newBreeze, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
        </form>
        </header>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd party libraries -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/q.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>        
    <script src="Scripts/breeze.savequeuing.js"></script>        

    <!-- App libraries -->
    <script>app = {};</script>        
    <script src="app/dataservice.js"></script>
    <script src="app/viewModel.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

viewmodel.js
app.viewModel = (function ( dataservice) {

    var vm = {
    newBreeze: ko.observable(""),    
    addItem: addItem    
    };


    return vm; // done with setup; return module variable

    //#region private functions

    function addItem() {
    var item = dataservice.createTodo(
        {
        BreezeName: vm.newBreeze()
        }
    );

    dataservice.saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

    vm.newTodo("");

    function addFailed() {
        console.log("Failed")
    }
    }
    function extendItem(item) {
    if (item.isEditing) return; // already extended

    item.isEditing = ko.observable(false);        

    }


})(app.dataservice);

// Bind viewModel to view in index.html
ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Breeze makes the metadata call under two conditions, either implicitly as part of the first query in an application or explicity via the EntityManager.fetchMetadata method.  This means that if you are **not** performing a query as your first action, then you will need to make a 'fetchMetadata' call instead.  Remember that this is an async call that returns a 'promise', just like a query, so you will need to perform any calls to your "createEntity" methods when the promise resolves (i.e. within the 'then' call.